# HTTPS connection java CertificateException

Tags: java, soap, https, certificate

We have certificate for domain.com, but we need to send soap message to sub.domain.com.
We have added that certificate to java cacerts. Created SOAPConnection as:

```
SOAPConnectionFactory scf = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection connection = scf.createConnection();
MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();

SOAPMessage msg = factory.createMessage();

SOAPMessage message = connection.call(msg, new URL("https://sub.domain.com/"));
```

And while sending message this way we get exception:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching sub.domain.com found
```

We need to get another certificate for domain sub.domain.com or there is another possible methods to trust all subdomains of domain.com?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you either need:

1. A [wildcard certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate); or
2. A certificate with [subject alternative names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) listed for all of your subdomains

Comment: Without changing the certificate just using existing certificate can we somehow send request to subdomain?